# SRSWOR involving Weighting

Tags: sampling, weights

A Simple Random Sample Without Replacement (SRSWOR) survey is conducted that included too many women and not enough men in the sample

In the resulting weighting, each female is given a weight of 1 and each male respondant is given a weight of 1.5.

This sample included 600 women and 380 men, of whom 400 women and 100 men respond Yes to a particular question of interest.

Give an estimate and standard error for the proportion of adults who would answer Yes to this question?

I understand how to do this regularly it is just the weightings have thrown me off and i am becoming confused.

Initially I would have thought the estimate would be:

500/980 = 0.51

However with the weightings I am not sure if this is still the correct answer.

With the standard error I would have again found the sample error(s) of each sex but again what do i do with the weightings?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you